# Numeric Validation when using a HTML Text Box

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Just learning about Validation, so I had defined a property on my model like this:

```
public string NumberOfThings { get; set; }
```

and a HTML for it like this:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.NumberOfThings , new {style = "width: 10%", @class = "form-control"})
```

Now I want to add validation to it, the data is saved as String in Database schema.  My validation logic want it to say **any number larger than 0 is OK.**

So I learned about validation and that I can do things like this:

```
[StringLength(3, MinimumLength = 1)]
public string SelectedQuestions { get; set; }
```

and then was aboe to see that oh my `ModelState` is not valid.
But since I am new to this I couldn't figure out what is the correct validation I should annotate my property with so that it says **any number larger than 0 is OK.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a number of something is an int not a string.

you can do something like :

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "some message")]
public int NumberOfThings { get; set; }
```

in your html you then use ValidationFor and it will look at what you have defined in your model:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberOfThings )
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumberOfThings )
```